# Disable 'find cursor' shortcut in iTerm2

Tags: shortcut, iterm

By default iTerm2 uses shortcut `⌘/` to find cursor on screen.
And I want the sortcut `⌘/` to apply to another action.
But I can't find out how to do this on new version of iTerm2.
How to disable `find cursor` shortcut in iTerm2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to define the key sequence in another app, then make iTerm2 ignore it:

1. Go to iTerm2 **Preferences...** --> **Keys**
2. Click on `+` under the grid
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> with cursor in the **Keyboard Shortcut** field
4. Leave the **Action** field value set to `Ignore`

If you want to use different action in iTerm2, assign the appropriate action in step 4.